Flutter website displaying a blank screen on desktop site mode, in mobe browser
I'm facing a weird issue and it is not getting fixed.
I created a flutter app which works fine on mobile devices - android/ios.
This same application was deployed as a PWA.
Now, this app works fine on web browsers when accessed from a laptop or a desktop.
After opening it from a mobile browser - it works fine and is able to load as expected. But when we check the 'Desktop site' option in chrome (from a mobile), it shows a white screen.
-> This is the ONLY case where it is showing a blank white page








Testing this on chrome web browser from mobile
Downloaded PWA in mobile devices is also working as expected.
Flutter version :
Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
Engine • revision 36335019a8
Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

Index.html file from the /web folder
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="*****">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="*****">


  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>

  <title>******</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Manifest.json file from the /web folder
{
    "name": "***",
    "short_name": "***",
    "start_url": "./index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "***",
    "theme_color": "***",
    "description": "***",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
}

How do i fix this issue? Any ideas?
Please let me know if I'm making any stupid mistakes.
P.S. - It is not working from android. But it seems to be working for iOS.

The Gray screen most probably that the app crashes I suggest you to regenerate the issue in debuging mode and let us know about the issue so we can help you

Hi @aymanomara. Actually this is not the grey screen which is shown when the app crashes. It's a complete white screen that's just not displaying the UI. And there are no API issues, or errors being shown on the console. There aren't even any warnings to indicate what could be going wrong here.

Hi @GopikaSingh I didn't face anything like that before, try another render if you are using HTML use canvas,  try navigate to another route while in desktop mode and lastly you may try to open issue in github flutter repository I think they may provide you with the best possible solution
